Why xcb_poly_segment doesn't draw to the pixmap?
I'm trying to make a simple xcb program to learn the basics and hopefully use it in another projects, but i encountered a strange problem. Having created a pixmap i can draw to it with the xcb_poly_fill_rectangle function and then the xcb_copy_area together with xcb_flush make it apear to the screen. The problem arrises when no matter what i try i can't make xcb_poly_segment draw some segments.
I'm new here so any recomendation or correction to the question i should make is well accepted.
Here is the code (maybe there is some extra unnecesary code regarding the question):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_image.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* Misc declarations */
    int screen_num;

    xcb_get_geometry_reply_t *window_size;
    
    xcb_generic_error_t **window_size_error;
    
    uint32_t mask;
    uint32_t values[3];
    /* Open the connection to the X server */
    xcb_connection_t *connection = xcb_connect(NULL, &screen_num);

    if (xcb_connection_has_error(connection)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: connection failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Get the current screen */
    const xcb_setup_t *setup = xcb_get_setup(connection);
    xcb_screen_iterator_t iterator = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup);

    for (int i = 0; i < screen_num; ++i) {
        xcb_screen_next(&iterator);
    }

    xcb_screen_t *screen = iterator.data;

    /* Create white (foreground) graphic context */
    xcb_gcontext_t white = xcb_generate_id(connection);
    mask = XCB_GC_FOREGROUND | XCB_GC_GRAPHICS_EXPOSURES;
    values[0] = screen->white_pixel; 
    values[1] = 0;

    xcb_create_gc(connection, white, screen->root, mask, values);

    /* Create text (foreground) graphic context */
    xcb_gcontext_t text = xcb_generate_id(connection);
    mask = XCB_GC_FOREGROUND | XCB_GC_BACKGROUND | XCB_GC_GRAPHICS_EXPOSURES;
    values[0] = 0x00FF00FF; 
    values[1] = 0xFF00FF00; 
    values[2] = 0;

    xcb_create_gc(connection, text, screen->root, mask, values);

    /* Create black graphic context */ /* Eraseable */
    xcb_gcontext_t black = xcb_generate_id(connection);
    mask = XCB_GC_FOREGROUND | XCB_GC_GRAPHICS_EXPOSURES;
    values[0] = screen->black_pixel; 
    values[1] = 0;

    xcb_create_gc(connection, black, screen->root, mask, values);

    /* Create a window */
    mask = XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
    values[0] = screen->black_pixel; /* bg color */
    values[1] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE;

    xcb_window_t window = xcb_generate_id(connection);
    xcb_create_window(connection,
                      XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
                      window,
                      screen->root,
                      0, 0,
                      640, 360,
                      10, 
                      XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
                      screen->root_visual,
                      mask, values);

    /* Map the window on the screen and flush*/
    xcb_map_window(connection, window);
    xcb_flush(connection);

    /* Eraseable */
    xcb_segment_t segments[] = {
        {50, 50, 100, 100},
        {50, 100, 100, 50},
    };

    xcb_rectangle_t rectangle = {
        0, 0,
        50, 50
    };

    xcb_pixmap_t pixmap = xcb_generate_id(connection);
    xcb_create_pixmap(connection, screen->root_depth, 
            pixmap, window, 16, 16);

    /* draw primitives */
    xcb_generic_event_t *event;
    xcb_expose_event_t *ex_event;
    while ((event = xcb_wait_for_event(connection))) {
            switch (event->response_type & ~0x80) {
            case XCB_EXPOSE:
                /* Eraseable */
                ex_event = (xcb_expose_event_t *) event;

                xcb_poly_fill_rectangle(connection, pixmap, white, 1, &rectangle);

                xcb_poly_segment(connection, pixmap, white, 2, segments);

                xcb_copy_area(connection, pixmap, window, white, 
                        ex_event->x, ex_event->y, 
                        ex_event->x, ex_event->y, 
                        ex_event->width, ex_event->height);


                /* Reflush */
                xcb_flush(connection);
                break;
            case XCB_KEY_PRESS: 
                /* TODO */
                break;
            default:
                break;
            } 
            free(event);
    }

    xcb_disconnect(connection);
 
    return 0;
}

I've tried changing the drawable for xcb_poly_segment to be the window and to call the function after copying the pixmap (so it doesn't overwrite) and works fine exept i cannot use the "text" graphics context and some other variations of the same but didn't work.
Also i searched for a way to know of any errors the poly segment function returns through the cookie. I suppose i didn't search hard enough.
Any response is well appreciated.
EDIT: FOUND THE ANSWER, but not the explanation :(
For reasons unknown to me the xcb_flush function was breaking something. Playing with the window i could get my way to see the segments for a brief period of time and then disappear into the void of existence. I assume it was trying to refresh to quickly or the flush was to slow to catch up but i have no idea.
Also fixed the really small size of the pixmap (smaller than the area required to draw the rectangle and the segments).

I did the following changes to your program:
--- t.c.orig    2024-07-02 17:07:30.085952668 +0200
+++ t.c 2024-07-02 17:11:07.498782376 +0200
@@ -86,12 +86,16 @@ int main(void)
 
     xcb_rectangle_t rectangle = {
         0, 0,
-        50, 50
+        300, 300
     };
 
     xcb_pixmap_t pixmap = xcb_generate_id(connection);
     xcb_create_pixmap(connection, screen->root_depth, 
-            pixmap, window, 16, 16);
+            pixmap, window, 300, 300);
+
+    /* I moved this up here since it only draws to the pixmap and that one keeps its content */
+    xcb_poly_fill_rectangle(connection, pixmap, white, 1, &rectangle);
+    xcb_poly_segment(connection, pixmap, black, 2, segments);
 
     /* draw primitives */
     xcb_generic_event_t *event;
@@ -102,10 +106,6 @@ int main(void)
                 /* Eraseable */
                 ex_event = (xcb_expose_event_t *) event;
 
-                xcb_poly_fill_rectangle(connection, pixmap, white, 1, &rectangle);
-
-                xcb_poly_segment(connection, pixmap, white, 2, segments);
-
                 xcb_copy_area(connection, pixmap, window, white, 
                         ex_event->x, ex_event->y, 
                         ex_event->x, ex_event->y, 


I moved the drawing to before the main loop since the pixmap retains its content. There is no need to re-draw it.
I changed the size of the pixmap to 300x300 so that it actually large enough to contain the lines you want to draw
I changed the size of the rectangle to fit the size of the pixmap
I changed the xcb_poly_segment() call to use the black GC instead of the white one. Drawing white on white has no visible result.

The result looks like this, which I hope is what you expect:


Thanks for the quick response. I will point out that even though moving the poly_fill_rectangle and poly_segment out of the loop it is understandable in this simple code the intent was for it to draw shapes that change over time. But in general thanks for the help :).
